# Error in file Handling in NodeJS : 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'

Tags: javascript

```
//load the module
let fs = require("fs");
let message = "Welcome to simple file handling program using Node JS";
fs.writeFile("demo1.txt",message,(err) =>{
    if(!err){
        console.log("Information stored in file successfully");
    }
    else{
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

I am getting the following error in the above Node JS program:

C:\Users\Dell\OneDrive\Documents\Phase - 3\Node JS Programs\Fs Module Programs>node AsyncWriteOperations.js
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
throw err;
^

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Dell\OneDrive\Documents\Phase - 3\Node JS Programs\Fs Module Programs\AsyncWriteOperations.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Comment: It says `AsyncWriteOperations.js` doesn't exist. Probably you made a typo in the filename.

Comment: Yes, it solved my error :)